# Bypass Squid proxy for SFTP request coming from servers which reside on private subnet on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, squid, sftp

I have setup an environment on AWS for a client. I have used squid forwards proxy instead on NAT gateway to allow internet to the servers which reside in a private network on AWS. It is working fine. But now i also want to allow users to connect to SFTP from one of my private Centos server. I have configured squid proxy as a NAT instance by using AMI from AWS. I googled every possible thing and finally came here. Can anybody please help me to achieve this. Any possible solution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should specify more details of your topology if you want someone to produce a ready to use solution for you. With such description, you'll receive at best a general help. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology

Comment: Thank you Marco. I have a server which resides inside a private subnet where internet is not accessible. To access internet we have route traffice to public subnet where i have a proxy server which accepts traffic from private servers and go to internet. Http requests work fine with squid but i want to handle sftp request from private server to internet. Is this possible with squid or i need to do some other settings to make this work.